# Save the Post ID from wp_insert_post($post); into a text file?

Tags: wp-insert-post

I'd like to create some posts using wp_insert_post and then save the created posts' Titles and ID's into a text file for future reference. How could this be done?

Comment: `wp_insert_post` returns the inserted post's ID, which you can then use in the file you want to write to. http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php

Answer (score 1):

You use [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action)!

Like this:

```
function save_id_to_file($post_id){
 //use your file creation/save function here
 return $post_id;
}

add_action('wp_insert_post','save_id_to_file');
```